# linking problem with dlfcn DLFCN-WIN32 library

Tags: c++, linker, scons

I am currently trying to use the DLFCN-WIN32 library in order to use a c++ script originally implemented to use the dlfcn.h library.

When compiling the code (cantera V2.3), everything goes well except when generating the shared library where the dlopen and dlclose functions are not found.

originally script is :

```
/**
 *  @file CustomKinetics.cpp 
 *
 * @ingroup chemkinetics
 */

//
// Author: Q. Cazeres, A. Felden, P. Pepiot 
//
//
#include "cantera/kinetics/CustomKinetics.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
 
using namespace std;

namespace Cantera 
{
  CustomKinetics::CustomKinetics(thermo_t* th) : GasKinetics(th) 
  {
    printf("WARNING: Using customized kinetics from f90 file.\n");
    handle = dlopen("customkinetics.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    // load symbol 
    ck = (ck_t) dlsym(handle, "customkinetics_");

  }

  void CustomKinetics::get_wdot_reduced(doublereal* wdot)
  {

    doublereal P = thermo().pressure();
    doublereal T = thermo().temperature();
    // New yarc2 format
    //doublereal rho = thermo().density();
    const doublereal* m_y = thermo().massFractions();

    ck(&P,&T,&m_y[0],&wdot[0]);

    // New yarc2 format
    //ck(&P,&T,&rho,&m_y[0],&wdot[0]);

    // Old yarc format
    //mol/kmol conversion cantera is in kmol
    for (size_t i=0;i<thermo().nSpecies();i++) {
        wdot[i]=wdot[i]/1000.0;
    }
  }
```

The script is compiled with the following command line :

```
g++ -o build\src\kinetics\CustomKinetics.o -c -std=c++0x -lpsapi -O3 -Wno-inline -g -Wall -include src/pch/system.h -DNDEBUG -Iinclude -Iinclude\cantera\ext -Ibuild\src -Ibuild\src\L -Isrc\L -IL:\LIB_WINDOWS\DLFCN-WIN32\include -IL:\LIB_WINDOWS\BOOST\boost_1_78_0 src\kinetics\CustomKinetics.cpp
```

The shared library is compiled with the following command line :

```
scons: warning: Using $CXX to link Fortran and C++ code together.
        This may generate a buggy executable if the 'g++'
        compiler does not know how to deal with Fortran runtimes.

g++ -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -shared -o build\lib\cantera_shared.dll build\ext\libexecstream\exec-stream.o build\ext\fmt\fmt\format.o build\ext\fmt\fmt\ostream.o build\ext\fmt\fmt\posix.o build\ext\sundials\src\sundials\sundials_band.o build\ext\sundials\src\sundials\sundials_dense.o build\ext\sundials\src\sundials\sundials_direct.o build\ext\sundials\src\sundials\sundials_iterative.o build\ext\sundials\src\sundials\sundials_math.o build\ext\sundials\src\sundials\sundials_nvector.o build\ext\sundials\src\sundials\sundials_pcg.o build\ext\sundials\src\sundials\sundials_sparse.o build\ext\sundials\src\sundials\sundials_spbcgs.o build\ext\sundials\src\sundials\sundials_spfgmr.o build\ext\sundials\src\sundials\sundials_spgmr.o build\ext\sundials\src\sundials\sundials_sptfqmr.o build\ext\sundials\src\nvec_ser\fnvector_serial.o build\ext\sundials\src\nvec_ser\nvector_serial.o build\ext\sundials\src\cvodes\cvodea.o build\ext\sundials\src\cvodes\cvodea_io.o build\ext\sundials\src\cvodes\cvodes.o build\ext\sundials\src\cvodes\cvodes_band.o build\ext\sundials\src\cvodes\cvodes_bandpre.o build\ext\sundials\src\cvodes\cvodes_bbdpre.o build\ext\sundials\src\cvodes\cvodes_dense.o build\ext\sundials\src\cvodes\cvodes_diag.o build\ext\sundials\src\cvodes\cvodes_direct.o build\ext\sundials\src\cvodes\cvodes_io.o build\ext\sundials\src\cvodes\cvodes_sparse.o build\ext\sundials\src\cvodes\cvodes_spbcgs.o build\ext\sundials\src\cvodes\cvodes_spgmr.o build\ext\sundials\src\cvodes\cvodes_spils.o build\ext\sundials\src\cvodes\cvodes_sptfqmr.o build\ext\sundials\src\ida\ida.o build\ext\sundials\src\ida\ida_band.o build\ext\sundials\src\ida\ida_bbdpre.o build\ext\sundials\src\ida\ida_dense.o build\ext\sundials\src\ida\ida_direct.o build\ext\sundials\src\ida\ida_ic.o build\ext\sundials\src\ida\ida_io.o build\ext\sundials\src\ida\ida_sparse.o build\ext\sundials\src\ida\ida_spbcgs.o build\ext\sundials\src\ida\ida_spgmr.o build\ext\sundials\src\ida\ida_spils.o build\ext\sundials\src\ida\ida_sptfqmr.o build\src\base\Parser.o build\src\base\ValueCache.o build\src\base\application.o build\src\base\checkFinite.o build\src\base\clockWC.o build\src\base\ct2ctml.o build\src\base\ctexceptions.o build\src\base\ctml.o build\src\base\global.o build\src\base\plots.o build\src\base\stringUtils.o build\src\base\xml.o build\src\thermo\ConstCpPoly.o build\src\thermo\ConstDensityThermo.o build\src\thermo\DebyeHuckel.o build\src\thermo\Elements.o build\src\thermo\FixedChemPotSSTP.o build\src\thermo\GibbsExcessVPSSTP.o build\src\thermo\HMWSoln.o build\src\thermo\HMWSoln_input.o build\src\thermo\IdealGasPhase.o build\src\thermo\IdealMolalSoln.o build\src\thermo\IdealSolidSolnPhase.o build\src\thermo\IdealSolnGasVPSS.o build\src\thermo\IonsFromNeutralVPSSTP.o build\src\thermo\LatticePhase.o build\src\thermo\LatticeSolidPhase.o build\src\thermo\MargulesVPSSTP.o build\src\thermo\MaskellSolidSolnPhase.o build\src\thermo\MetalSHEelectrons.o build\src\thermo\MineralEQ3.o build\src\thermo\MixedSolventElectrolyte.o build\src\thermo\MixtureFugacityTP.o build\src\thermo\MolalityVPSSTP.o build\src\thermo\MolarityIonicVPSSTP.o build\src\thermo\Mu0Poly.o build\src\thermo\MultiSpeciesThermo.o build\src\thermo\Nasa9Poly1.o build\src\thermo\Nasa9PolyMultiTempRegion.o build\src\thermo\NasaPoly2.o build\src\thermo\PDSS.o build\src\thermo\PDSS_ConstVol.o build\src\thermo\PDSS_HKFT.o build\src\thermo\PDSS_IdealGas.o build\src\thermo\PDSS_IonsFromNeutral.o build\src\thermo\PDSS_SSVol.o build\src\thermo\PDSS_Water.o build\src\thermo\Phase.o build\src\thermo\PhaseCombo_Interaction.o build\src\thermo\PureFluidPhase.o build\src\thermo\RedlichKisterVPSSTP.o build\src\thermo\RedlichKwongMFTP.o build\src\thermo\SemiconductorPhase.o build\src\thermo\SingleSpeciesTP.o build\src\thermo\Species.o build\src\thermo\SpeciesThermoFactory.o build\src\thermo\SpeciesThermoInterpType.o build\src\thermo\StoichSubstance.o build\src\thermo\SurfPhase.o build\src\thermo\ThermoFactory.o build\src\thermo\ThermoPhase.o build\src\thermo\VPSSMgr.o build\src\thermo\VPSSMgrFactory.o build\src\thermo\VPSSMgr_ConstVol.o build\src\thermo\VPSSMgr_General.o build\src\thermo\VPSSMgr_IdealGas.o build\src\thermo\VPSSMgr_Water_ConstVol.o build\src\thermo\VPSSMgr_Water_HKFT.o build\src\thermo\VPStandardStateTP.o build\src\thermo\WaterProps.o build\src\thermo\WaterPropsIAPWS.o build\src\thermo\WaterPropsIAPWSphi.o build\src\thermo\WaterSSTP.o build\src\tpx\CarbonDioxide.o build\src\tpx\HFC134a.o build\src\tpx\Heptane.o build\src\tpx\Hydrogen.o build\src\tpx\Methane.o build\src\tpx\Nitrogen.o build\src\tpx\Oxygen.o build\src\tpx\RedlichKwong.o build\src\tpx\Sub.o build\src\tpx\Water.o build\src\tpx\lk.o build\src\tpx\utils.o build\src\equil\BasisOptimize.o build\src\equil\ChemEquil.o build\src\equil\MultiPhase.o build\src\equil\MultiPhaseEquil.o build\src\equil\vcs_Gibbs.o build\src\equil\vcs_MultiPhaseEquil.o build\src\equil\vcs_SpeciesProperties.o build\src\equil\vcs_TP.o build\src\equil\vcs_VolPhase.o build\src\equil\vcs_elem.o build\src\equil\vcs_elem_rearrange.o build\src\equil\vcs_inest.o build\src\equil\vcs_nondim.o build\src\equil\vcs_phaseStability.o build\src\equil\vcs_prep.o build\src\equil\vcs_prob.o build\src\equil\vcs_rearrange.o build\src\equil\vcs_report.o build\src\equil\vcs_rxnadj.o build\src\equil\vcs_setMolesLinProg.o build\src\equil\vcs_solve.o build\src\equil\vcs_solve_TP.o build\src\equil\vcs_solve_phaseStability.o build\src\equil\vcs_species_thermo.o build\src\equil\vcs_util.o build\src\numerics\BandMatrix.o build\src\numerics\CVodesIntegrator.o build\src\numerics\DAE_solvers.o build\src\numerics\DenseMatrix.o build\src\numerics\Func1.o build\src\numerics\FuncEval.o build\src\numerics\IDA_Solver.o build\src\numerics\ODE_integrators.o build\src\numerics\ResidJacEval.o build\src\numerics\RootFind.o build\src\numerics\SquareMatrix.o build\src\numerics\funcs.o build\src\numerics\polyfit.o build\src\kinetics\AqueousKinetics.o build\src\kinetics\BulkKinetics.o build\src\kinetics\C12H26_25_373_27_TJKinetics.o build\src\kinetics\C12H26_NOX_27_452_20_TJKinetics.o build\src\kinetics\C2H4_18_320_11_AFKinetics.o build\src\kinetics\C3H8_22_173_12_FCKinetics.o build\src\kinetics\C7H16_25_210_27_FCKinetics.o build\src\kinetics\CH4_22_320_18_TJKinetics.o build\src\kinetics\CustomKinetics.o build\src\kinetics\Falloff.o build\src\kinetics\FalloffFactory.o build\src\kinetics\GasKinetics.o build\src\kinetics\Group.o build\src\kinetics\HYCHEM_27_272_12_AFKinetics.o build\src\kinetics\HYCHEM_NOX_29_548_17_AFKinetics.o build\src\kinetics\ImplicitSurfChem.o build\src\kinetics\InterfaceKinetics.o build\src\kinetics\Kinetics.o build\src\kinetics\KineticsFactory.o build\src\kinetics\Reaction.o build\src\kinetics\ReactionPath.o build\src\kinetics\RxnRates.o build\src\kinetics\importKinetics.o build\src\kinetics\solveSP.o build\src\kinetics\c12h262537327tj.o build\src\kinetics\c12h262745220tj.o build\src\kinetics\c2h41832011af.o build\src\kinetics\c3h82217312fc.o build\src\kinetics\c7h162521027fc.o build\src\kinetics\ch42232018tj.o build\src\kinetics\hychem2727212af.o build\src\kinetics\hychemnox2954817af.o build\src\kinetics\sankaran13.o build\src\transport\AVBPTransport.o build\src\transport\DustyGasTransport.o build\src\transport\GasTransport.o build\src\transport\HighPressureGasTransport.o build\src\transport\LTPspecies.o build\src\transport\LiquidTranInteraction.o build\src\transport\LiquidTransport.o build\src\transport\LiquidTransportData.o build\src\transport\LiquidTransportParams.o build\src\transport\MMCollisionInt.o build\src\transport\MixTransport.o build\src\transport\MultiTransport.o build\src\transport\SimpleTransport.o build\src\transport\SolidTransport.o build\src\transport\SolidTransportData.o build\src\transport\TransportBase.o build\src\transport\TransportData.o build\src\transport\TransportFactory.o build\src\transport\TransportParams.o build\src\transport\WaterTransport.o build\src\oneD\Domain1D.o build\src\oneD\MultiJac.o build\src\oneD\MultiNewton.o build\src\oneD\OneDim.o build\src\oneD\Sim1D.o build\src\oneD\StFlow.o build\src\oneD\boundaries1D.o build\src\oneD\refine.o build\src\zeroD\ConstPressureReactor.o build\src\zeroD\FlowDevice.o build\src\zeroD\FlowReactor.o build\src\zeroD\IdealGasConstPressureReactor.o build\src\zeroD\IdealGasReactor.o build\src\zeroD\Reactor.o build\src\zeroD\ReactorBase.o build\src\zeroD\ReactorFactory.o build\src\zeroD\ReactorNet.o build\src\zeroD\ReactorSurface.o build\src\zeroD\Wall.o build\src\clib\ct.o build\src\clib\ctfunc.o build\src\clib\ctmultiphase.o build\src\clib\ctonedim.o build\src\clib\ctreactor.o build\src\clib\ctrpath.o build\src\clib\ctsurf.o build\src\clib\ctxml.o -Lbuild\lib -Lbuild\src\L -Lsrc\L -LL:\LIB_WINDOWS\DLFCN-WIN32\lib -Wl,--out-implib,build\lib\libcantera_shared.a -Wl,--output-def,build\lib\cantera_shared.def
```

And after that I got the following error message :

```
=====
b"build\\src\\kinetics\\CustomKinetics.o: In function `Cantera::CustomKinetics::CustomKinetics(Cantera::ThermoPhase*)':\r\nL:\\LIB_WINDOWS\\CANTERA\\cantera-avbp-2.3/src/kinetics/CustomKinetics.cpp:23: undefined reference to `dlopen'\r\nL:\\LIB_WINDOWS\\CANTERA\\cantera-avbp-2.3/src/kinetics/CustomKinetics.cpp:26: undefined reference to `dlsym'\r\nbuild\\src\\kinetics\\CustomKinetics.o: In function `Cantera::CustomKinetics::close_dl()':\r\nL:\\LIB_WINDOWS\\CANTERA\\cantera-avbp-2.3/src/kinetics/CustomKinetics.cpp:53: undefined reference to `dlclose'\r\nL:\\LIB_WINDOWS\\CANTERA\\cantera-avbp-2.3/src/kinetics/CustomKinetics.cpp:53: undefined reference to `dlclose'\r\ncollect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status\r\n"
=====
scons: *** [build\lib\cantera_shared.dll] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

The include and lib directories of the DLFCN-WIN32 libraries are well put in argument with -L option. Did I forget a compilation option?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Rock

Comment: You need to actually link the libraries using `-l` option

Comment: Please post the entire build log. Along with which version of python, which version of SCons, which compiler(s)?